# Initializer-string for char array is too long using deduction of size

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm using gcc 4.8.5 and I'm getting the error:

```
error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [-fpermissive]
  char filebase[] = "file name base";
                    ^
```

The code snippet this comes from is a private char array that's part of a class:

```
class MyClass {
    char filebase[] = "file name base";
public:
    /* constructor, destructor, functions, none of which use the value */
};
```

I thought this was legal in C++ per this link: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/

Which states:

"Therefore, the array of char elements called myword can be initialized with a null-terminated sequence of characters by either one of these two statements:"

```
char myword[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
char myword[] = "Hello";
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: added the actual error message and fixed the syntax in my code snippiet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify an initialiser in the class, remember that that's still only the *default* field initialiser. A constructor could override it. That's why the initialiser cannot have any effect on the array's length, and why this cannot work.

clang produces a better diagnostic:

> error: array bound cannot be deduced from an in-class initializer

The reason GCC's diagnostic is so confusing is because it conflicts with a GCC extension. If you pass GCC the `-pedantic` option, you get an additional warning (and again somewhat misleading):

> warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'filebase'

GCC is accepting your field definition of type `char[]`, and gives it length `0`. It then does not accept your initialiser, since it doesn't fit in a zero-length array.

To make it work, specify the array's size explicitly.

Comment: I get `error: flexible array member ‘MyClass::filebase’ in an otherwise empty ‘class MyClass’` with gcc 6.1, which is more useful for figuring out what gcc is thinking.

Comment: @melpomene That's a much better diagnostic, glad to see it's improved now. Even 5.3 (which is pretty recent) still gave the same diagnostic the OP showed.

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to use a `const char *` for the original scenario? Since that would purely point to the string somewhere else in memory rather than creating a new char array for every class instance.

Comment: @MitchLaskis It depends on what you want to do with the string, but yeah, that is an option. That wouldn't allow you to modify the string contents, it would allow you to change the pointer to point to a different string, but it wouldn't allow you (at least not easily) to store dynamically constructed strings with automatically managed lifetime.

Comment: @MitchLaskis If you don't need to modify it, you could also just make the array `static` (I think).